# Why does including something in the SOAP header prevent it from matching an XSLT template?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, soap

I have a SOAP (1.1) envelope something like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:l3="http://tempuri.org/l3">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <l3:requestType>Valid</l3:requestType>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <l3:xyzRequest xsi:schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/l3 lds.xsd " requestId="7291655" functionalId="1645885" appChannel="XYZ" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <workpackageId>126381</workpackageId>
      ...
    </l3:xyzRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And a XSLT template something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/l3:xyzRequest">
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2013 (.NET Framework 4.5.1). Here's the transformation code:

```
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform(false);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

xslt.Load(@"<XSLTPath>");

using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xslt.OutputSettings))
{
    xslt.Transform(XML.CreateReader(), xw);
}
```

When I run the transform, the template is not matched, but if I remove the `<l3:requestType>` element from the SOAP Header (without making any other changes), it works fine. Anyone have a clue as to why?

**EDIT:**

Per the requests to provide more code, here is a minimal sample that will reproduce the issue:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

namespace Project1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            XDocument XSL = XDocument.Parse("<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:l3=\"http://tempuri.org/l3\" version=\"1.0\">" +
                    "<xsl:output method=\"xml\" />" +
                    "<xsl:template match=\"soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/l3:xyzRequest\">" +
                        "<Test><xsl:value-of select=\"workpackageId\" /></Test>" +
                    "</xsl:template>" +
                "</xsl:stylesheet>");
            XDocument XML = XDocument.Parse("<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:l3=\"http://tempuri.org/l3\">" +
                    "<soapenv:Header>" +
                        "<l3:requestType>Valid</l3:requestType>" +
                    "</soapenv:Header>" +
                    "<soapenv:Body>" +
                        "<l3:xyzRequest xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://tempuri.org/l3 lds.xsd \" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" +
                            "<workpackageId>126381</workpackageId>" +
                        "</l3:xyzRequest>" +
                    "</soapenv:Body>" +
                "</soapenv:Envelope>");
            XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform(false);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            xslt.Load(XSL.CreateReader());

            using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xslt.OutputSettings))
            {
                xslt.Transform(XML.CreateReader(), xw);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

If you run that, the template is not matched and you get the default behavior of returning the value of all nodes: `Valid<Test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:l3="http://tempuri.org/l3">126381</Test>`; however, if you comment out line 21 (`"<l3:requestType>Valid</l3:requestType>" +`), the template *is* matched, and you get the expected result: `<Test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:l3="http://tempuri.org/l3">126381</Test>`.

**EDIT 2:**

Whoops, just noticed that the first result I posted above isn't quite the default behavior, but it isn't well-formed XML, which is what threw me off. Sorry about that -- should've looked closer when copying and pasting! I guess the question now is: when an element is included in the SOAP Header, why is its value returned, even though that was not intended from the XSLT template?

Comment: Please show us more than 2 lines of your XSLT. The part you showed us isn't the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among the most obvious possible reasons why a template intended to match the l3:xyzRequest elements in the input might be producing no results are:

- The input might not have any l3:xyzRequest elements.  If the input fragment you show is correct, this is not your problem.
- The match pattern on the template might not match the intended elements; this can result from misspelled names, errors binding namespace prefixes, or problems in the formulation of the XPath expression.  At first glance, this doesn't appear to be your problem.
- The stylesheet may never ask the processor to handle that element.  (More concretely:  there may be no xsl:apply-templates instruction that includes the l3:xyzRequest element among the nodes it selects.)  Without seeing your stylesheet in full, it's impossible to confirm that this is the cause of your problem, but it can't be ruled out.

You say that if removing a different element from the input causes the transform to "work fine".  I'll guess that that means the template does produce output from the l3:xyzRequest element in that case.  That suggests that some conditional based on the presence or absence (or the value) of the other element is affecting the stylesheet processing.

My advice would be to start cutting down the stylesheet until you have the smallest possible stylesheet which exhibits the behavior you're trying to change ('works fine' when the l3:requestType element is missing, breaks when it's present).  When you get it down to twenty lines or so, the answer will either be obvious or relatively easy for some Stack Overflow reader to find.

[Addendum] Once one disentangles the XML and XSLT in your code from the C# it's intermixed in, you have this XML instance:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                  xmlns:l3="http://tempuri.org/l3">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <l3:requestType>Valid</l3:requestType>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <l3:xyzRequest xsi:schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/l3 lds.xsd " 
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <workpackageId>126381</workpackageId>
    </l3:xyzRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

to be processed with this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                xmlns:l3="http://tempuri.org/l3" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />
  <xsl:template
      match="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/l3:xyzRequest">
    <Test><xsl:value-of select="workpackageId"/></Test>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Running this stylesheet on this XML produces the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


    Valid


    <Test xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:l3="http://tempuri.org/l3">126381</Test>
```

It's not clear to me why you believe the template is not matching.

The string 'Valid' is appearing in the output because you have not overridden the built-in default templates (which process elements by recurring on their children, and text nodes by copying the text nodes to the output).

Comment: Thanks for the info, and my apologies for not being more clear! The XSLT was already cut down to the bare minimum, but that was not obvious from what I posted. I have edited my post with a complete code sample that I hope will make the problem easily reproduceable. Thanks again for your assistance!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I did not realize that it was recursive over all children of an element.